# IntersectionType doesn't work with class-transformer

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Suppose we have a following intersected class

```
export class PagingDto {
  @IsInt()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @ApiProperty()
  limit: number;

  @IsInt()
  @Type(() => Number)
  @ApiProperty()
  offset: number;
}

export class UserDto {
  @IsString()
  @ApiProperty()
  name: string;
}

export class UserWithPagingDto extends IntersectionType(
  PagingDto,
  UserDto,
) {}
```

When I tried to use it with @Query(), nestjs does not transform limit & offset string value to number as intended...

```
// ----- in UserController
@Get()
  find(@Query() dto: UserWithPagingDto) {
    console.log(dto)
    // output: { limit: '10', offset: '1', name: 'foo' }
    // limit & offset should be numbers...
  }


// ----- in main.ts, following config is defined to enable validation with transform
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({ transform: true }),
  );
```

If I simply put everything written in PagingDto in UserWithPagingDto, it works fine.

Does this mean nest does not support class-transformer with IntersectionType or is there any workaround?

Comment: Add `transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true }` as an option to the `ValidationPipe`. Side note: what's the `...app.get(Reflector)` there for?

Comment: Thank you for your comment! but setting `transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true }` result in the same... :(  // `...app.get(Reflector)` -> sorry this was for ClassSerializerInterceptor... I removed this from the sample code

Comment: Interesting. The code looks like this should be fine. Any chance you have a repo where I can test this?

Comment: Thank you again. I tried to reproduce it with a new minimum repository, but in the new project, somehow limit & offset are numbers, working just fine as expected... But now I know at least nest supports intersectionType with transformer, I'll dig a little deeper on my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class-transformer works with IntersectionType with minimum configuration:
`app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({transform: true}));`
It was just a @nestjs/swagger library's version issue.
In my case, bumping up from nestjs 7 to 8 (effectively bumps up @nestjs/swagger from 4.5.12-next.1 to 5.1.2) fixed the problem.

<off the topic, but useful note>
if `transformOptions: { enableImplicitConversion: true }` option is enabled, it converts string to number even without `@Type(() => Number)` decorator.

(Big thanks for [@Jay McDoniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9576186/jay-mcdoniel))

Comment: I should note that `@nestjs/swagger@^4` is for `@nestjs/common@^7` and `@nestjs/swagger@^5` is for `@nestjs/common@^8`